# Resize images before training object detection

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, object-detection

I am training an object detector. I didn't resize my image before labeling because the of assumption that the model does this automatically to fit its `input shape`.

this was the decision I made before labeling many images. now I am seeing a slow performance (maybe for the big resolution or maybe for other reasons...)

So, do I have to reduce the sizes by my self? isn't it a `useless redundant` task because it does it anyways before feeding to the network?

is this so important that I should have to go back resize and LABEL all my hundreds of image **again**??

Comment: why would resizing require re-labeling? it's a mystery to me. you need re-think your data processing

Comment: I think you need to give more information on what model you are using and what framewokr you are talking about. But usually your images are not fit to the size of the input shape. In Python there are fucntion which can resize your images

Comment: I had to use the labelimg tool to label the images. so If I am to resize them, I should recalibrate the coordinates in the generated xml files to match those of the new resolution.

I am using the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_ppn` model. I may write a simple batch resizing script, but the problem is with the label xmls, which I will have to regenerate for the new resolution.
but is it actually necessary? wouldn't the model already resize it to its inputshape? for example the one i mentioned `ssd_mobilenet_v1_ppn` uses 300 x 300 images.